# Macbook 2007 (A1181) Wi-Fi issues in Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, network, windows, wifi, bootcamp

I have:

- Macbook A1181
- Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp with the latest patches
- All bootcamp drivers installed
- Keenetic Viva router with 2.4/5 GHz dual-band Wi-Fi, located in ~1m from the Macbook

The issue is that download/upload speed via Wi-Fi is very low in any app (~60kbps) and often interrupts. On the other hand, ethernet connection works great.

And the same Macbook works great with Wi-Fi when I boot macOS, but, unfortunately, I need Windows.

Other devices, like M1 Macbook Pro (late 2020), iPhones and lots of Android phones (even 2.4 GHz) work fine too, so it seems to be a driver issue.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Damaged/corrupt drivers are the bane of Windows admins. I would remove the driver in device manager, reboot and see if it changes behavior. Failing that reinstall the WiFi driver from the Apple driver package downloadable from Apple's Boot Camp support pages.

Comment: I've removed the driver, and after reboot it seems to be restored with no visible improvement

Comment: Do you try the Windows application called Apple Software Update?